# mount.ntfs taking up 99% of cpu

Tags: mount, wubi, ntfs, automount, cpu

I dual-boot Ubuntu and Windows with WUBI, version 12.04, and have been recently running into some issues. Every once in a while, I run top and see that mount.ntfs is taking up all of my cpu. It is impossible to do any other tasks, and takes a few minutes just to get a terminal open.

Since I use WUBI, mount.ntfs is always running in the background, but is using up little to none cpu. It's large usage seems to be triggered whenever I make large changes to the disk, usually extracting a large zip file. Even after it finishes, the large cpu usage continues.

Recently, it also happens whenever I try to run apt-get install, it starts to eat up cpu after 98% of the repos are checked.

Is there any fix for this? I should also note that the zip files, when I restart, dissapear.

Comment: The fix is to install Ubuntu properly to a dedicated partition. Wubi is not  intended for serious suage, but rather for evaluation and testing.

Comment: Yes, I know. Is there a way to fix it in the meantime?

Comment: You mean like fixing the `ntfs-3g` driver code? Sure, grab [the source](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/) and start hacking!

Answer (score 1):

Wubi is known to be significantly slower when processing large archive files. [Reference on Phoronix.com](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ubuntu_wubi_1010&num=2)

But It sounds like you might have some other flakiness. Maybe try running `fsck` on the `root.disk` - either from a live CD, or in recovery mode.

I'd recommend backing up beforehand (either data or the entire `root.disk`). For Wubi installs it's a good idea to always have up to date backups.